# How to combine multiple rows of pandas dataframe into one between two other row values python3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a single column that contains name, address, and phone info separated by blank or na rows like this:

```
   data
0  Business name one
1  1234 address ln
2  Town, ST 55655
3  (555) 555-5555
4  nan
5  Business name two
6  5678 address dr
7  New Town, ST 55677
8  nan
9  Business name three
10 nan
```

and so on...

What I want is this:

```
   Name                 Addr1             Addr2               Phone
0  Business name one    1234 address ln   Town, ST 55655      (555) 555-5555
1  Business name two    5678 address dr   New Town, ST 55677
2  Business name three
```

I am using python 3 and have been stuck, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

- create groups for each row with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)
- for align with non NaN rows add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html)
- remove `NaN`s by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html), [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to `MultiIndex` with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)
- reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)

---

```
a = df['data'].isnull().cumsum().reindex(df.dropna().index)
print (a)
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
5    1
6    1
7    1
9    2
Name: data, dtype: int32
```

---

```
df = df.dropna().set_index([a, a.groupby(a).cumcount()])['data'].unstack()
df.columns = ['Name','Addr1','Addr2','Phone']
print (df)
                     Name            Addr1               Addr2           Phone
data                                                                          
0       Business name one  1234 address ln      Town, ST 55655  (555) 555-5555
1       Business name two  5678 address dr  New Town, ST 55677            None
2     Business name three             None                None            None
```

If there is multiple `address` is possible create columns dynamically:

```
df.columns = ['Name'] + 
             ['Addr{}'.format(x+1) for x in range(len(df.columns) - 2)] +
             ['Phone']
```

Comment: This is excellent and has introduced some new ideas for combining methods using python and pandas! Thank you jezrael!

Answer (score 0):

```
df['group']=df['data'].str.contains('Business').cumsum().replace({True:1}).ffill()
df1=df.groupby('group')['data'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).dropna(axis=1,thresh =1)
df1.columns=['Name','Addr1','Addr2','Phone']

df1
Out[1221]: 
                      Name            Addr1               Addr2  \
group                                                             
1.0      Business name one  1234 address ln      Town, ST 55655   
2.0      Business name two  5678 address dr  New Town, ST 55677   
3.0    Business name three              NaN                 NaN   
                Phone  
group                  
1.0    (555) 555-5555  
2.0               NaN  
3.0               NaN
```